# DB2 - IN vs. JOINS

Tags: sql, db2

I found some information regarding IN, JOINS and EXISTS, and there efficiency. But for me my question was never really answered, or the answer was not clearly stated.
My examples produce the same results.

Here are the two examples:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID)
  FROM  A
       ,B
       ,C
 WHERE A.ID = B.ID
   AND B.ID = C.ID 
   AND 'SOME OTHER CONDITIONS';

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID)
  FROM A
 WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT B.ID
                  FROM B
                      ,C
                 WHERE B.ID = C.ID
                   AND 'SOME CONDITION')
   AND 'SOME CONDITION';
```

Running against a hundreds of millions of rows, is one of them clear more proficient than the other?

Comment: ...it's going to depend entirely on the distribution of values in each of those tables, and what indices you have.  So we can't answer without a **lot** more information, and you may be able to better answer this question yourself.  In general, (inner) joins tend to allow the optimizer to knock out non-matching rows sooner, although if you have duplicate rows from that it may increase resources needed for the `DISTINCT`.  Under some conditions the optimizer may generate identical plans for both queries.

Comment: `...is one of them clear more proficient than the other?` Not if (as you say in your question) "{your} examples produce the same results." Results should differ in terms of resources used or time, if one is much better in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out in SQL with 100000 records and a very similar query without the conditions and saw the execution plan. The output result is the same for both.
Both have a query cost of 50%. 
Also with statistics on, 1st has 3891 physical reads on table2 and 425 on table1, while the other has 4593 physical reads on table2 and 79 on table1. The logical reads and the read-ahead reads were almost similar for both the queries.
So clearly both queries work the same way.

My Query

```
Select count( distinct table1.column)
From table1 join table2
on table1.column= table2.column;

Select count (distinct column)
From table1
Where column in 
         (Select distinct column
          from table2);
```

But, when I use `Select column` and not the `count(distinct column)` i.e. not aggregated, join have a query cost of 5% as compared to the other which has 95% and all reads are many times less in joins.

So for non-aggregated queries 'Joins' are more efficient than 'In'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how much rows you "eliminate" from the inner select. If the inner select returns few rows it will be faster to execute the "IN". However I don't think there will be much difference, maybe the first example could use more memory because it need to store in memory the whole cartesian product of the three tables.

Unrequested hint: write your join conditions like this: `FROM B JOIN C ON (B.ID = C.ID)`, it will be more clear, and in your WHERE clauses you will only have necessary conditions. Anywhere this won't effect performance, it was just a suggestion